# AutoSPInstaller New-SPSite : No User Profile Application available to service the request

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to do a SharePoint deployment into my dev environment using AutoSPInstaller, but keep receiving a ***No User Profile Application available to service the request*** when it gets to the point of creating the site collection.

I am using the latest release and I'm using the supplied config file, albeit with the correct server names, account names, etc. for my environment.

I've used this scripts plenty of times before but have never received this before and it's got me stumped. I know I can work around, but want to know why the scripts aren't working straight off codeplex or is anyone else has ever had this happen to them?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had added spWebAppPool user as local admin prior to running the new-spsite command. After reading another post I took a wild guess and removed him from local admin group. It worked!